# Java GC runs tuning impacts

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have been running my application with both initiliaze and maximum set as 256Mb. So after sometime I notice that I got 2 GC ready. Below is what I managed to capture a snippet of my jstat. I would like to know what normally cause the Old Generation to grow and once its full is where we get full GC right. I have not set both the initialize and maximum memory to 512 Mb. Is there any other tuning I must do based on generation values?

```
      2752448.4   0.00  61.25  99.06  51.71  44.17   4613  235.614     2    0.429  236.044
      2752453.4   0.00  61.25  99.73  51.71  44.17   4613  235.614     2    0.429  236.044
      2752458.3  69.74   0.00   0.44  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
      2752463.3  69.74   0.00   1.31  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
      2752468.4  69.74   0.00   2.67  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ./jstat -gcutil -t 1824 5s
[root@localhost bin]# ./jstat -gcutil -t 1824 5s
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
      2752472.6  69.74   0.00   3.67  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
      2752477.6  69.74   0.00   5.38  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
      2752482.6  69.74   0.00   7.51  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
      2752487.6  69.74   0.00   9.52  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
      2752492.6  69.74   0.00  10.55  51.72  44.17   4614  235.630     2    0.429  236.059
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know what normally cause the Old Generation to grow and once its full is where we get full GC right.

Anything which leaves the survivor space will in the old gen.  You might only get a major collection when the old gen fills. A full collection is for both young and old.

> . I have not set both the initialize and maximum memory to 5125 Mb

I suspect you mean 512 MB (note Mb = mega-bit)

> Is there any other tuning I must do based on generation values?

Without more information, I would not "tune" the GC any more. In fact I would remove the minimum setting unless you know this really helps.  I don't even set the maximum unless I know this helps.

Comment: before I set 256Mb I used to get a lot of GC then I set it I only then to get now FULL GC say in 2 weeks times. What will normally leave the survivor space any thing we can dig or indicate something ? Yes my mistake its 512Mb now. I did not set the minimum setting I just the initial and maximum. Should I remove both now ?